# WebApi doesn't get published?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, asp.net-web-api

I currently have two controllers. One is MVC and the other is a WebApi controller.
I've published these two with ease on the IIS server with the following settings:

WebApiConfig:

```
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

RouteConfig:

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "MVCControllerName", action = "MVCControllerName", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Now I've added another WebApi controller, but when published, the webserver says:

> No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

```
http://example.com/folder/api/Other?id=45&text=bla
```

Implementation of the `OtherController`:

```
    public void Get(int id, string text)
    {
         // something simply gets commited to the DB
    }
```

Also, something weird is happening when publishing... I've deleted the first WebApi controller from the solution, but for some reason when publishing I can *STILL* call that WebApi through HTTP GET request! Even though it's gone!

OTOH, it works fine in the debug mode..

What's going on here?

EDIT: It seems the problem is not in my code, but in VS' publishing feature. It has *always* worked until now. I had to manually copy the files to the server, which isn't the point of so-called "one-click publishing". Other similar SO questions seem to indicate it is a VS bug that is still not fixed in SP2.

Comment: how are you publishing it?

Comment: Looks a route issue, routeTemplate: "api/{controller}?{id}" only accepts routes with id, you can't reach the two parameter controller with this configuration, add "api/{controller}/{id}/{text}" as well.

Comment: @Jonesy I'm using the VS publishing functionality that replaces files through FTP on the web server.

Comment: @Fals No dice. I still get a 404 when trying to call the new webapi.

Comment: Theres a precedence order, put this route first!